# Cannot select value of a textbox inside of gridview

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridview, textbox

My grid view has a textbox inside of TemplateField. I'm trying to get the value of a textbox when button is clicked:

This is where I define a textbox:

```
<ItemTemplate>
         <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEmail" Text='<%#Eval("CustEmail") %>' />
         <asp:Button id="btnUpdate" Text="Update Email" ButtonType="Button" CommandName="UpdateEmail" 
               ValidationGroup="grpEmail" 
               Visible="true" runat="server"
               OnClientClick="ValidateEmail()" />

         </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

This is my javascript:

```
        function ValidateEmail()
        {
           var email = $(this).closest('tr').find('#txtEmail').val();
           alert(email);
        }
```

My `alert` box displays "undefined"

Which is the right way to do here?

Thank you

Comment: I don't think 'this' has any meaning in that context. Try to put $('#btnUpdate').click(function() { ValidateEmail($this); }); in the js-file and change ValidateEmail to take the parameter "affected" or something, then let "...email = $(affected)..."

That should do the trick, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Since `id` is unique, you can use:

```
var email = $('#txtEmail').val();
alert(email);
```

Comment: I tried that already. I get "undefined" in my alert. Email field is a part of a GridView and is defined inside of the `TemplateField` as shown in my code example

Answer (score 0):

$(this) doesn't mean anything within such a function, you should use event listeners if you want to refer to $(this) :)

Refer directly to your field by $('#txtEmail')

Comment: I have `OnClientClick` event triggering ``ValidateEmail`

Comment: Yes it corresponds to classic click event